# No audio coming from HDMI ouput (Kubuntu, Radeon RX 480)

Tags: drivers, hdmi, amd-graphics, amdgpu

My Radeon RX 480 video card refuses to put out audio through HDMI connection. I tried installing the latest driver and prioritizing HDMI output in my settings, but nothing really seemed to work. In Pulse Audio it recognizes HDMI but it says `Line out (unplugged)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got things working in case anyone else want to know. It may save you some time.

The problem seemed to be that pulse audio was send sound to card 1 device 3 which produced no sound with sound-test command. I needed to switch it to card 1 device 7, which did produce sound with sound-test.

I added two lines to the file `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

```
load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:1,7
```

The `hw:1,7` corresponds to the "card 1" and "device 7" shown for the device in the output of the `aplay -l`. This was the card and device that played sound from sound-test.

On your computer, the card number and device changes. Adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt with the same issue, and believe it to be related to the bug described in this thread: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1834771

Reverting to a version of the Linux kernel that is 4.15.0-50 or earlier should also fix the problem. The reason appears to be that the amdgpu driver is not setting a certain parameter (eld_valid) correctly, and versions of the kernel from 4.15.0-51 onwards check for this, while older versions don't.

For me, even on a new kernel, installing module-echo-cancel in PulseAudio also created a working sound connection via the new virtual device it sets up. This may be an option for anyone who doesn't mind having an echo-cancelled mic/speaker pair on their system. More info on that module: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Enable_Echo/Noise-Cancellation (it's the best info I've found even though it's not Ubuntu-specific)